# TinyMCE add list automatically with space key

Tags: html, tinymce

I have a div box which will get the tinymce extension like this:

```
<div id="notice"></div>

<script>
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#notice',
  inline: true,
  menubar: false,
  skin: "oxide-dark",
  toolbar: 'bold italic bullist',
  plugins: ['lists','autoresize','textpattern'],
  toolbar_location: 'bottom',
  deprecation_warnings: false
});
</script>
```

I would like to realize that a list will be automatically generate if I write something like this:

```
- my first list item
```

this works, but only If I press the enter key at the end.
Problem: The enter key create directly a new list item, which I have to delete manually if I would like to have only one item (more steps as needed)

Result looks like this:

[image]

Any idea, how can I solve it without pressing the enter key?